# Page function doesn't work for multlingual Website. How can i fix it?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, parameters

I wanted to make my website multilingual, as far no problem, and everything is working.

Now i wanted to use mod_rewrite, therefore i copied my .htacces file and did the same with an additional parameter. So far all good.

Now i clicked arround and faced the issue that my page function does not work anymore when i use the additional parameter (see example below) - i really can not find the problem, i hope someone can help me.

**Example:**

*Works -->* 
https://www.airdropbob.com/index.html?page=2

*Doesn't work -->* 
https://www.airdropbob.com/ru/index.html?page=2 (shows me page1)
BUT if i use it without my rewritten url it works: https://www.airdropbob.com/index.php?lg=ru&page=2

So it seems i did a mistake in my htaccess file.

**My .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.airdropbob\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.airdropbob.com/$1 [R=301,L]
###############ENGLISH REWRITE################
#Website
RewriteRule    ^index.html?$    index.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^cryptocurrency-projects?$    projects.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^airdrop-calender?$    calender.php    [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^contactus?$    contactus.php    [NC,L]  
#Airdrop
RewriteRule    ^airdrop-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+).html?$    airdrop.php?action=show&id=$2    [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^airdrop/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)?$    airdrop.php?action=show&id=$2    [NC,L]  
#Project
RewriteRule    ^ads/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$    index.php?action=out&id=$1     [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^link/([0-9]+)?$    airdrop.php?action=out&airdropid=$1     [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^project-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+).html?$    projects.php?action=show&projectid=$2    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)?$    projects.php?action=show&projectid=$2    [NC,L]  
###############Other Language REWRITE################
#Website
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   index.php?lg=$1    [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/index.html?$    index.php?lg=$1    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/cryptocurrency-projects?$    projects.php?lg=$1    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/airdrop-calender?$    calender.php?lg=$1    [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/contactus?$    contactus.php?lg=$1    [NC,L]
```

Can someone help me to find the issue? 
I have no idea anymore :/

Thank you!

Comment: Just fixed it now in a different way - I extended my url within the page parameter and have it directly included in the rewriterule statement, now it works. Still wondering how i could solve the upper problem